# Can't bind to 'ng-model' since it isn't a known property of 'input'

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

Start learning Angular 2 , for this error tried almost all links in stack-overflow but still , please help me understand why still produces error even after import **FormsModule**

This is my customer.ts file

```
export class Customer {

  public CustomerName: string = "asdsad";
  public Code: string = "asdsa";
  public Amount: string = "asdasd";
}
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { Customer } from "./Customer"

@Component({
selector: 'my-app',
moduleId: module.id,
templateUrl: './st.html'           
})

   export class AppComponent {
customerobj: Customer = new Customer();
   }
```

app.module.ts

```
            import { NgModule } from "@angular/core"
            import { BrowserModule } from "@angular/platform-browser"
            import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
            import { AppComponent } from "./app.component"
            @NgModule({
                imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule ],
                declarations: [AppComponent],
                bootstrap: [AppComponent]
            })

            export class AppModule { }
```

main.ts

```
    import { platformBrowserDynamic } from "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic"

    import { AppModule } from "./app.module"

    platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

[image]

Comment: Post your HTML code

Comment: use ngModel instead of ng-model

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> You must have used "ng-model" inside input tag

**For Angular2/4 use ngModel**

`ng-model` is For angular 1

`ngModel` is For angular 2

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/15679200)

Comment: Thanks for guiding.

Comment: Thank you saved me a lot

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using **ng-model** instead of **ngModel**

Change it as **`ngModel`**.

Since you have not posted the component.html,

It should be,

```
<input [ngModel]="custoermerObj.Code"></input>
```

Comment: Thank you for valuable time ,

Answer (score 0):

Use `[(ngModel)]` instead of `[(ng-model)]`

Comment: Thank you for valuable time.